# Unable to receive grab event by using GRAB_EVENT_MASK?

Tags: java, swing, events

I added an AWTEventListener to process grab event. So this listener just use sun.awt.SunToolkit.GRAB_EVENT_MASK
mark.
But This listener can not capture UngrabEvent. The tricky thing is, when a JComboBox popuped its menulist, it can capture this event.
I use the following code for testing.
Start the program, click on the empty area of the frame, click on the frame title. Then there should be an UngrabEvent. But the listener does not capture it.
Start the program, click on the combobox and make its menulist popuped. click on the
frame title. Then there should be an UngrabEvent. And the listener captures it.
It is very strange...Is there any relationship between UngrabEvent and JComboBox?

```
public class ComboboxLearn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        toolkit.addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event);
            }
        }, sun.awt.SunToolkit.GRAB_EVENT_MASK);
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" });

        box.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);// Set a breakpoint here
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(box);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I've never heard of the grab or ungrab events, but maybe if you explain what you are trying to accomplish someone can provide an alternative approach.

Comment: JComboBox uses popup list. But the popup list will hide if I mouse pressed or some key pressed. I wanna a popup that will hide when mouse pressed outside the popup but not hide when mouse press on the popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense you're experimenting; but generally, you shouldn't rely on Sun/Oracle's undocumented APIs.

> I want a popup that will hide when the
>   mouse is pressed outside the popup but
>   not hide when the mouse is pressed on the popup.

Why not bring up a `JDialog` when you see `isPopupTrigger()` and hide it when you see it deactivating, as another window activates? The notion is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245206/230513).

Comment: It is glad to seem some discussion on this problem.
In the discussion, the problems is not resolved. And the workaround it not about Popup, it is about PopupMenu.

Comment: Yes, it looks rather platform specific. I'd consider another approach using the standard API, as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Although trashgod's reasoning is understandable, it doesn't answer the question: What you are actually trying to do won't work because for the grab even to fire, you need to have a window *grabbed*: `((SunToolkit)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()).grab(someWindow);`.

You could change your code as follows

```
class ComboboxLearn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        toolkit.addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event);
            }
        }, sun.awt.SunToolkit.GRAB_EVENT_MASK);
        JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new Object[] { "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" });

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        box.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener() {

            @Override
            public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);// Set a breakpoint here
                //UNGRABBING WINDOW
                ((SunToolkit) toolkit).ungrab(f);
            }

            @Override
            public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                //GRABBING WINDOW
                ((SunToolkit) toolkit).grab(f);
            }
        });

        f.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(box);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then you will get your grab events **but** at the level you are working on you don't need them.

#### Then when would I need them?

Assuming you run into [this nasty bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4799266) which although closed, I could still reproduce it, you need to implement your own popup mechanism. You did everything fine you attached your AWT listeners to close the popup whenever there is a click outside it but something is missing. You click everywhere and the popup disappears except on the window captions and outside your application! Shoot you think! How does JPopupmenu do it. And after you spend some time reading jdk code and trying various stuff, you realize that it's this undocumented event that does the trick.

I don't know the internals of this `grab()` method and I don't have time to investigate so there might be side effects not very obvious. Call it on your own risk.