# Using JPopupMenu + JTextField for a quick search

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` that displays business data. To make it more usable, I want to add a popup menu when right-clicking the column header which simply displays a text input field which serves as the input for a filtering.

It's easy to add a popup menu when right-clicking on the column header and to put a `JTextField` inside it. However, I would like the text field to automatically gain focus so that the user can instantly start typing rather than having to focus the text field first.

**Relevant code (fully working SSCCE below):**

```
final JTextField filter = new JTextField( 20 );
final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.add( filter );

table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed( MouseEvent event ) {
        if( !event.isPopupTrigger() ) {
            return;
        }

        popup.show( table, event.getX(), event.getY() );
        // TODO focus the text field
    }
} );
```

At the `TODO` comment's location I tried things like `filter.requestFocusInWindow()`, but that doesn't work. I assume that the popup menu itself is stealing the focus. How can I force the text field to gain focus when the popup is triggered?

Alternatively if there is a better way to display a text field popup I'd be glad to see that, too :)

**SSCCE:**

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Test {
    private static final JTable table = new JTable( new Object[][] {
        { "Foo", "Bar" }
    }, new Object[] {
        "A", "B"
    } );

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        final JTextField filter = new JTextField( 20 );
        final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add( filter );

        table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed( MouseEvent event ) {
                if( !event.isPopupTrigger() ) {
                    return;
                }

                popup.show( table, event.getX(), event.getY() );
                // TODO focus the text field
            }
        } );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( table ) );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Comment: I added an SSCE as a link.

Comment: If it's an SSCCE, it is short enough to add as an edit to the question..  Why link?  BTW - the SSCCE Document will go off the net at the end of the month.  ;)

Comment: I'd like the question to focus on the relevant code rather than imports and other (typically) irrelevant things. I'd expect someone with the same problem to be able to at least create a `JTable` without me having to show them how to do it.

Comment: Cool, it's your choice.  But I'm not following a link, and some people **cannot** follow links (by employer rules).  The way you *might* handle it is to leave the 'to the point' code where it is, but mention 'MCTaRE below'..  Personally, I can only really read code once it is (compiled and formatted the way I like it) in my editor.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I copied the SSCE to the end now. And I feel you on the formatting issue.

Comment: surprisingly, a plain field.requestFocus worksforme while requestFocusInWindow doesn't work. Might be highly OS/version dependent (currently on win7, jdk7)

Comment: I have tried with FocusListener  , but NetBeans complete the the methods with exception:- throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); able.getTableHeader().addFocusListener( new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {

            public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {
                popup.show( table, 50,10 );
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

            }

            public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                popup.show( table, 50,10 );
   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
        });

Comment: @kleopatra Both didn't work for me (Ubuntu) and unfortunately this has to be cross-platform (and has to work with jdk6). I get it to work using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`, but that's just… uncomfortable. I'd really like having a quick&easy text field popping up.

Comment: yeah, focus issues are nasty: whatever you do and get working on one platform might not work on another :-( One trick left: wrap the focus request into invokeLater, sometimes it helps (though didn't make a difference for requestInWindow here)

Comment: I'm not so much into workarounds because they contradict quality standards (this would actually go into a fairly big application). If Swing has no way of doing this "right", I guess I will just have to settle for `showInputDialog`. :/

Comment: `BTW - the SSCCE Document will go off the net at the end of the month.` @AndrewThompson, Why? There ares more than one forum on the web. I use the `SSCCE` link on all the other web sites. Other web sites (like Java Ranch) even recognize `SSCCE` as a keyword and will generate the link for you.

Comment: @camickr  2 factors.  1) I was getting 4 domains hosted for free.  The web host decided that web hosting was not working for them, and has decided to drop that entire side of the business.  2) The SSCCE.org domain name was secured by a 3rd party, and offered to me for use.  The 3rd party got in contact with me and mentioned it comes up for renewal in March, and they wanted to transfer it to me.  I told them 'thanks, but the SSCCE itself is disappearing'.  -- I cannot really justify the expense or hassle of keeping either going.  OTOH, if someone were to volunteer, I could transfer it to them..

Comment: @camickr  I would also be happy for (e.g.) Java Ranch to host their own version of the SSCCE document. (ran out of space in last comment..)

Comment: @camickr  I [made them an offer](http://www.coderanch.com/t/628405/Ranch-Office/SSCCE-org-document-disappearing)..

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I understand not wanting the expense. Everything I do on the web involves free hosting, blogging etc. Nice that you made Java Ranch an offer. Anyway, it was good while it lasted. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

> I get it to work using JOptionPane.showInputDialog(), but that's just… uncomfortable. I'd really like having a quick&easy text field popping up.

Instead of trying to implement this using `JPopupMenu`, do it with an undecorated `JDialog`. It's somewhat more flexible but requires you to say when it is no longer needed, unlike a `JPopupMenu`. The latter isn't really intended to house text fields.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {

        final JTable table = new JTable(new Object[][]{
            {"Foo", "Bar"}
        }, new Object[]{
            "A", "B"
        });
        final JTextField filter = new JTextField(20);
        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this);
        dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.setUndecorated(true);
        dialog.add(filter);
        dialog.pack();

        Action hideAction = new HideAction(dialog);
        ActionMap actionMap = filter.getActionMap();
        InputMap inputMap = filter.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);        
        actionMap.put("hideAction", hideAction);
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "hideAction");
        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0), "hideAction");

        filter.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            }

        });

        table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                if (!event.isPopupTrigger()) {
                 return;
                }
                showDialog(event);
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                if (!event.isPopupTrigger()) {
                 return;
                }
                showDialog(event);
            }

        private void showDialog(MouseEvent event) {
            Point convertedPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(
                    table.getTableHeader(), event.getPoint(), Test.this);
            Point locationOnScreen = Test.this.getLocationOnScreen();
            locationOnScreen.translate(convertedPoint.x, convertedPoint.y);
            dialog.setLocation(locationOnScreen);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            // do whatever
        }
        });

        add(new JScrollPane(table));
        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Test frame = new Test();                
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    private static class HideAction extends AbstractAction {

        final JDialog target;

        public HideAction(JDialog target) {
            this.target = target;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            target.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Just in case you are still looking for an answer, 6 months later. Yes, I was bored.</sup>

Answer (score -4):

I would like the text field to automatically gain focus so that the user can instantly start typing rather than having to focus the text field first.

Hope this helps.

```
table.getTableHeader().setFocusable(true);

filter.setFocusable(true);

table.getTableHeader().addFocusListener( new java.awt.event.FocusListener() {

 public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe) {

popup.show( table, 50,10 );

 throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

 }

public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
                //do something
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

}
});
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense at all.

Comment: What the mistake in my answer can you please explain?

Comment: Have you tried running it? For one, it will always throw exceptions. Removing that you are left with code that will always open the popup (not when it is actually triggered) and it will trap the focus (at least on some platforms making it impossible to exit the application). And on top of that typing still won't work. In other words it's not just wrong, it's even dangerous.